# ERROR URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?) because of browsers

Tags: ruby, http, browser, sinatra, uri

I have some special characters on some of my url's. For example:

`http://blabla.com/title/?t=burası`

When I am giving links to that pages from other pages, I use:

```
URI.encode(s)
```

which produces this link:

```
/title/?t=buras%C4%B1
```

While everything is normal until this point, also I have another form on the page which has the encoded url. But browsers tend to decode my encoded url when users visits `/title/?t=buras%C4%B1` and turns the url into `/title/?t=burası` . The problem begins here because when the user tries to send something from the form on 'burası' page, sinatra gives an error:

`ERROR URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): http://localhost:3000/title/?t=burası`

I think it is because of HTTP request's 'referrer' string, but I couldn't find any workarounds as long as browsers tend to decode the string automatically.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal working example? I'm unable to reproduce -- see this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/2891784).

Answer (score 3):

You should encode the URI in the FORM method.

For example, make your HTML FORM action look something like this:

```
<form action="/title/?t=buras%C4%B1" method="post">
```

Does that solve it for you?

(Edit: thanks x1a4 for the correction-- of course you're right! :)

Comment: You've switched the `action` and `method` attributes in your example.